# How to replace a expression when using a filter in Java?

Tags: java, android

I am working on a piece of coursework in android, it returns a list of takeaways to the screen, listing their address, the distance from my location, and a hygiene rating and I struggling to set up the filter to filter out ratings that don't meet the criteria i.e -1

Thus in these cases I want to return "exempt" to the screen. This is what I have so far

```
 for (int i = 0; i < ja.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject JO = (JSONObject) ja.get(i);
                        // if the rating of the restaurant is -1, exempt
                        // should be displayed
                            ratingValue.stream()
                                .filter(x->x.equals("-1"))
                               << ifPresent.>>  (System.out.println("Exempt"));

                        {
                            ConcatenateSearchResults();
                        }
```

The ifPresent that seems to exist in Java, doesn't seem to exist in Android and the tutorials I tried don't assist me.

```
protected JSONArray doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        // if the searchUrl conversion is empty
        if (!searchUrl.toString().isEmpty()) {
            // do this instead
            try {
                URL url = new URL(searchUrl.toString());
                URLConnection tc = url.openConnection();
                InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(tc.getInputStream());
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(isr);

                String line;  // variable

                // while line in (read in) is not equal to null
                // create a new object and output as line in JSON
                while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                    ja = new JSONArray(line);

                    // run through the length of the array

                    for (int i = 0; i < ja.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject JO = (JSONObject) ja.get(i);
                        // if the rating of the restaurant is -1, exempt
                        // should be displayed
                        ratingValue.stream()
                                .filter(x -> x.equals("-1"))
                                .findFirst()
                                .ifPresent(v -> System.out.println("Exempt"));
                        ConcatenateSearchResults();

                        // output to meet Basic Functionality requirement
                        businessNames.add(JO.getString("BusinessName"));
                        postCodes.add(JO.getString("PostCode"));
                        addressList1.add(JO.getString("AddressLine1"));
                        addressList2.add(JO.getString("AddressLine2"));
                        addressList3.add(JO.getString("AddressLine3"));
                        ratingValue.add(JO.getString("RatingValue"));


                        calcDistance.add(JO.getString("DistanceKM"));
                    }
                }
                isr.close();
                in.close();
                //return ja;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                this.exception = e;

                return ja;
            } finally {
                //is.close();
            }
        }
        return ja;
    }
```

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

`ifPresent()` doesn't relate to the Android platform, its a part of Java.
In your case, `.filter()` the method returns another stream of filtered values, **not the single value, but a stream**.

So **you can't use `ifPresent()` on streams**, you need to obtain a single value. To make you code correctly, you can simply add `.findFirst()` before `ifPresent()`, this will return the first filtered value from `ratingValue`:

```
ratingValue.stream()
        .filter(x -> x.equals("-1"))
        .findFirst()
        .ifPresent(v -> System.out.println("Exempt")
```

Comment: Thank you. The programme has accepted it. However for some reason it is by-passing and still outputting -1.

Comment: not sure whether this is another question, the issue has arose from the first tho @ish